# ¿Cuál es el origen de "tirarse a alguien"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, coloquialismos, sexualidad

*Tirarse a alguien* quiere decir tener sexo con esa persona, pero de dónde viene esta expresión y por qué.

Esto suena a que cuando te tiras a alguien, la puedes 'tirar a la cama' en el sentido de arrojar, ¿pero viene realmente de ahí?

¿En qué años surge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por los resultados que estoy viendo en el CORDE, los primeros ejemplos de *tirarse a alguien* en el sentido sexual parecen tener lugar en la segunda mitad de la década de 1960, aunque la expresión con casi toda probabilidad vendrá de antes.

> *—Un quinto tenía que ser. Mira que llegas a ser tonta. ¿No sabes que los quintos son unos granujas que sólo buscan tirarse a las tontas como tú...?*
>
> Juan Marsé, "Últimas tardes con Teresa", 1966 (España).

Yo entiendo que el significado sexual se deriva de uno previo, y es el uso de *tirarse* como "arrojarse, abalanzarse" sobre alguien, con algún fin cariñoso o más intenso.

> *Carmen se tiró a él; lo cubrió de besos, mortaja la más preciada con que solamente una madre puede envolver, y Julito, insensible, seguía roncando, la mirada siempre allá, en el Misterio...*
>
> Federico Gamboa, "Suprema Ley", 1896 (México).

De este uso se derivaría *tirarse* sobre alguien como un eufemismo de poseerlo sexualmente.

Comment: Como en "_tirarse al ruedo_".